# how can I predefine the color of multicolumns?

Tags: tables, color, multicolumn

I'm trying to use multicolum. In my table all the columns have a predefined color which will be overwritten by multicolum. So my question is how can I define own or some more custom multicolumn commands which will make it able to set the color of the column faster than writing:

```
\multicolumn{3}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}} c|}{myText}
```

I tried something like this:

```
\renewcommand{\multicolumn}[3]{%
\oldmc{##1}{| {\columncolor[gray]{.8}[.5\tabcolsep] } c |  ##2}{ ##3 }% }}
```

But I think there are some problems with the syntax, as I don't get it working.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: @user25646 It looks like you've got two separate accounts: this one and one older unregistered one. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: thx, for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load package `array`

```
\usepackage{array}
```

define a new column type (say `Q`)

```
\newcolumntype{Q}{|>{\color[gray]{.8}} c|}
```

then use

```
\multicolumn{3}{Q}{myText}
```

Comment: Which is surely better than redefining `\multicolumn`, of course. `:-)`